# Recurrence : $T(n) = 4T(n/2) + Θ(n^2/\log n)$

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

Is there a way to solve this recurrence using master theorem:

$$T(n) = 4T(n/2) + Θ(n^2/\log n)$$

Comment: This is Case 2b on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Yuval Filmus in the comment, you can use the extension of [the master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) (case 2b). The result is $T(n) = \Theta(n^2 \log\log{n})$.